# Can't debug Windows Service -"attach to process"

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

[Microsoft instructions state the following](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3.aspx)

> In Visual Studio, choose Attach to Process from the Debug menu.
>
> The Processes dialog box appears.
>
> Click Show system processes.
>
> In the Available Processes section, click the process for your
>   service, and then click Attach.

However, I don't see the "Show system processes." option.
I've tried checking off the other options but my service doesn't show up in the list.

[image]

Yes, I've installed and started the services and can see it in the in service manager.

I'm also aware that It's not possible to debug onstart. However, I have a continuous loop running.

Comment: this worked for me http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/261190/How-to-Debug-or-Test-your-Windows-Service-Without

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work for me. Get error"can't start service from command line ...."

Comment: Try to check "Show processes from all users" checkbox, select managed code" in "Attach to" dropdown and refresh processes list

Comment: Yuriy, unfortunately your suggestion didn't help. Still don't see the service in the list. Thanks for trying.

Comment: The continuous loop doesn't run in OnStart, does it?

Comment: @boruchsiper, if @Yuriy's suggestion didn't help, maybe your service is immediatly get crushed after start? Just take a look at Task Manager to see if your's service process exist or look at `System` event log for erros.

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem? If so, please mark accordingly :)

Answer (score 17):

You must do the following:

1. Open your solution in Visual Studio Administrator mode.
2. Make sure your service is running.
3. Open the "Attach to process window"
4. Make sure both checkboxes are checked (all users, all sessions).
5. Find the name of your executable in the list.

If the above doesn't work, you will need to provide some additional details about your setup. :-)

Answer (score 12):

You may add somewhere in service, for example in OnStart method this code:

```
#if DEBUG
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
#endif
```

On service start, you will get a prompt dialog to debug process. Don't forget to build in Debug mode and switch to Release in production

Comment: this works me to debug the function in service start, i just open the solution in visual studio to run as Administrator. then i add System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(); in Service Start function. thanks  @Yuriy

Answer (score 0):

Actually to allow the program to get the list of the processes of every user on the machine, that program must have administrative rights. Ensure you start visual studio with the corresponding account.

Comment: I started VS as administrtor but unfortunately I still couldn't see the service in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure *selected code type* settings are correct. You manage them by clicking the *[Select...]* button next to "Attach to:". In the image you attached, you have set it to "Automatic: Native code". Try some other settings. 
**Note:** Press *[Refresh]* button after you have changed the setting to update the list of processes shown.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the service might be different with the name of the process. The name of the process is probably the name of the service exe file. you can check this in task manager or in your windows service vs project. (the name that appears in the Attach Process window is the name of the process not the name of the service)

Answer (score 0):

By default processes not running under your account will be hidden, which is how services run by default unless you set them to run using a custom user.

Make sure show processes from all users is checked:
[image]